# Why does my Hyper-V suspend all its VMs once a day?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I experience a very strange problem when using Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Every day, around 10.30pm, all of my virtual machines become unreachable for a few minutes.

I have found out, that they are suspended and started again. Also, the uptime as shown by the Hyper-V Manager never reaches more than 24 hours.

I don't have any backup software or other scheduled tasks running. What could cause this problem?

Comment: Just to confirm is this Hyper-v on the free download iso, or did you install Hyper-v on the paid version of Windows Server? The free iso version uses WindowsPE. WindowsPE will not run for more than 24 hours to sway people from using WinPE as their primary OS.

Comment: We are talking about the paid version of Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition. It is not the primary OS that suspends or anything. Its only the VMs in the Hyper-V. Thanks

Comment: @RobinHood: Hyper-V Server is not Windows PE-based. It is a heavily stripped down version of Windows Server with only the bare essentials for virtualization, and it does not have an uptime limit. If the server software genuinely was WinPE-based, it would be the *host machine* that is rebooting, not the guest VMs. Besides, WinPE is limited to 72 hours continuous uptime, not 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a guess, but I would suspect it's rebooting every 24 hours based on it's expired.  run slmgr.vbs -rearm to extend the period.  If the systems were installed without a key this will happen after the first 90 days
Check the system eventlog on the vm to see if it's rebooting - look for kernel-power for the last startup time.  If it's around 10:30 you have your answer.
I don't spend time on this site, so don't look for any further input.